# How to retrive created_at data from database with eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, web, eloquent

How can i retrive created_data from database with eloquent in laravel ?, i'm using belongs to many relationship, i want to show the borrowed book data and the borrowed date, I have successfully displayed borrowed book data, but i cant get the created_at data from another table in database named borrow_history

Book.php

```
public function borrowed()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'borrow_history')
    ->withTimestamps();
}
```

User.php

```
public function borrow(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Book::class, 'borrow_history')
    ->withTimestamps();
}
```

This is my current HomeController.php index

```
public function index()
{
    $books = auth()->user()->borrow;
    return view('home', [
        'books' => $books,
    ]);
}
```

And i want to show the created_at data at the home.blade.php

```
@foreach($borrow_history as $borrow)
   <p>
      <i class="material-icons">date_range</i> Borrow_date : {{ ???? }}
   </p>
@endforeach
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you load a `belongsToMany` (many-to-many) relationship with Laravel, it will include a pivot property on the relationship. Since you have `withTimestamps()` on the relationship it will include the `created_at` and `updated_at` values.

You should be able to achieve what you're after with the following:

```
$borrow->pivot->created_at;
```

For more information you can refer to the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) (scroll down to **Retrieving Intermediate Table Columns**)